# Creating a new column with a function's output, row by row

Tags: r, function, if-statement

I have a data frame with a column of values (CVT_revenue$V4) ranging from 1 to 100. I want to apply a function to each of the values in the column and create a new column with the function's output. For example, if CVT_revenue$V4 had 45 in its first row, I would want the function to perform the calculation in the first else if statement, then put the output into the first row of the new column.

This is what I've tried:

```
actualRevenues <- function(df, column){
  for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
    if (column[i] < 33){
      df$actualRevenue <- (column[i] * 22000 + 300000)
    } else if(column[i] > 32 & column[i] < 67){
      df$actualRevenue <- ((column[i] - 32) * 33000000 + 1000000)
    } else {
      df$actualRevenue <- ((column[i] - 66) * 9090909 + 100000000)
    }
      }
}
actualRevenues(CVT_revenue, CVT_revenue$V4)
```

Since starting on this problem, I've learned that mapply might be the easiest way to accomplish what I want to do, but I'm not sure why my code isn't working. If I put a print statement after the else statement, I can see that it's calculating the same value over and over again. This is a snippet from the printed results:

```
    [1] 5.95e+08 5.95e+08 5.95e+08 5.95e+08 5.95e+08 5.95e+08 5.95e+08 5.95e+08 5.95e+08
  [10] 5.95e+08 5.95e+08 5.95e+08 5.95e+08 5.95e+08 5.95e+08 5.95e+08 5.95e+08 5.95e+08
  [19] 5.95e+08 5.95e+08 5.95e+08 5.95e+08 5.95e+08 5.95e+08 5.95e+08 5.95e+08 5.95e+08
  [28] 5.95e+08 5.95e+08 5.95e+08 5.95e+08 5.95e+08 5.95e+08 5.95e+08 5.95e+08 5.95e+08
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this, but the closest process to what you start with will lead you to ifelse. You want to use ifelse for a vectorized problem like this, not if(...) (this is why you're getting the same value over and over). You do not need a for () loop. Something like this will work:

```
df$actualRevenue <- ifelse(CVT_revenue$V4<  33, CVT_revenue$V4 * 22000 + 300000, 
                    ifelse(CVT_revenue$V4 > 32 & CVT_revenue$V4 < 67, (CVT_revenue$V4 - 32) * 33000000 + 1000000, 
                          (CVT_revenue$V4 - 66) * 9090909 + 100000000))
```

Here, the "else" condition becomes the last evaluated statement, that is, everything in V4 that is greater than 67. Best, Derek